# fish shell -eq and -a in if statement

Tags: git, shell, tab-completion, fish, completion

I was reading the git.fish completion script (/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.1.2/share/fish/completions) for fish shell and I ran into some problems with understanding what the syntax means.

In the block,

```
function __fish_git_needs_command
  set cmd (commandline -opc)
  if [ (count $cmd) -eq 1 -a $cmd[1] = 'git' ]
    return 0
  end
  return 1
end
```

I understand that `cmd` is set as `commandline -opc`. But in the next statement `(count $cmd) -eq 1 -a $cmd[1] = 'git'`, what do `-eq` and `-a` mean?

I am new to fish shell and I am trying to understand the syntax by trying to write my own completion script for a program. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In fact `-eq` and `-a` are not part of fish syntax. They are ordinary arguments!

```
if [ (count $cmd) -eq 1 -a $cmd[1] = 'git' ]
```

The opening square bracket here is actually a command, like cat or grep. You really do have a file `/bin/[`. It may be easier to understand via the `test` command, which is the same thing:

```
if test (count $cmd) -eq 1 -a $cmd[1] = 'git'
```

Now it's easy to see that `-eq` and `-a` are just ordinary arguments being passed to `test`, with no syntactic significance to fish.

`test` has its own little language like awk or sed. See `man test` to learn about it.

Comment: The only difference is that `test` is built into shell, so you save having to execute an external command.

Comment: Thank you for answering so well. TIL `/bin/[` is an executable in system.

Comment: Both test and [ are builtins in most shells, including fish. There's no performance difference.

Answer (score 2):

The `-eq` is an [*integer comparison function*](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

The `-a` is a [*logical and*](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

So the logical equivalent would be something like:

```
if [ (count $cmd) == 1 && $cmd[1] == 'git' ]
```

(in Java pseudo-syntax).

## Background

The reason why `-eq` is used is because a shell normally works with text processing only. As a result numbers are stored in "strings". Sometimes two numbers are equivalent, but not string-equivalent. For instance the following example:

```
if [ "01" -eq "1" ]
then
    echo "integer equal"
fi
if [ "01" = "1" ]
then
    echo "string equal"
fi
```

Will only print `integer equal`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Fish documentation](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#test) :

> - NUM1 -eq NUM2 returns true if NUM1 and NUM2 are numerically equal.
> - COND1 -a COND2 returns true if both COND1 and COND2 are true.

It tests that `(count $cmd) = 1` and that `$cmd[1] = 'git'`.
 (`=` here being equality, not an assignment).

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for that exact link. I looked all around the place using different search terms but just couldn't find it.